# Filter JSON based on value

Tags: json, jq

I am looking to grab the email address only from the records with the UserStatus = FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD.

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "Username": "",
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "Name": "sub",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email_verified",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email",
                    "Value": "john@example.com"
                }
            ],
            "UserCreateDate": "",
            "UserLastModifiedDate": "",
            "Enabled": true,
            "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED"
        },
        {
            "Username": "",
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "Name": "sub",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email_verified",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "email",
                    "Value": "jane@example.com"
                }
            ],
            "UserCreateDate": "",
            "UserLastModifiedDate": "",
            "Enabled": true,
            "UserStatus": "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've got the following expression below to work but now I need to figure out how to fetch the 3rd Value key that contains the email address while omitting the first 2 Value keys.

```
jq ".Users[] | select(.UserStatus | contains(\"FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD\")) | {UserStatus: .UserStatus, Values: [.Attributes[].Value]}" userlist.json
```

Comment: You state as a requirement that "UserStatus = FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD" but your program uses `contains`. Could you perhaps clarify what your actual requirement is?  Also, for future reference, it is usually a good idea to show the expected output.  See e.g. the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: @peak I'm wondering if used the wrong terminology/syntax and should have said contains rather use the equal sign.  I will be sure to use add an expected output in my next question. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The posted JSON is not quite valid, so the following assumes the superfluous comma has been removed.
2. With the corrected JSON, the posted program produces what one would expect:

```
{
  "UserStatus": "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD",
  "Values": [
    "",
    "true",
    "jane@example.com"
  ]
}
```

3. Since you indicate you only want the email address, you will probably want something closer to:

```
.Users[]
| select(.UserStatus | contains("FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD"))
| {UserStatus, email: (.Attributes | from_entries.email) }
```

which produces:

```
{
  "UserStatus": "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD",
  "email": "jane@example.com"
}
```

Or for just the value of .email:

```
.Users[]
| select(.UserStatus | contains("FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD"))
| .Attributes[]
| select(.Name == "email").Value
```

4. If you want to filter based on .UserStatus being equal to "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD", you would of course use `==`.
5. Notice that `UserStatus: .UserStatus` can be abbreviated to just `UserStatus` within a literal object specification.

Comment: You are amazing, I've corrected the JSON and tweaked the expression to produce a cleaner output as I only need the email address as a final product.  `jq -r ".Users[] | select(.UserStatus | contains(\"FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD\")) | (.Attributes | from_entries.email)" userlist.json`